# How to get a VM Flavours in IBM cloud through Softlayer Rest API

Tags: api, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to get a VM Flavours(Compute C1.2x2, Balanced B1.2x8) using Softlayer Rest API. I didn't find any API references related to get Flavours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the active VM flavors use the following rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getActivePresets
```

You will get a response like the below example:

```
[
  {
        "description": "B1.16x64x100",
        "id": 351,
        "isActive": "1",
        "keyName": "B1_16X64X100",
        "name": "B1.16x64x100",
        "packageId": 835
    },
    {
        "description": "C1.1x1x100",
        "id": 359,
        "isActive": "1",
        "keyName": "C1_1X1X100",
        "name": "C1.1x1x100",
        "packageId": 835
    },
]
```